Are there logical facts absolutely necessary in modal logic across possible and impossible worlds?
If we consider weird universes or ones in which impossibilia exist alon others. Are there any logical things or laws of thought which have to exist across all types of wild conceptions?
Roujd squares follow a type of logic? Or a type of world in which inplications do not necessarily hold etc.

How does a universe look like where impossibilia exist? It sounds like a contradiction "impossibilia exist".

Humans in this world have concaved of different flavors of logic, each with different rules of inference. We've actually shown more than mere conception, we've shown they are internally correct. Possible worlds where these logics can be related to statements in those worlds are by definition possible.

There are "absolutely necessary facts" in modal logic residing 'outside' of any possible or impossible world, the machinery needed to set up the system, see Forster, Modal aether. Some truths are necessary in virtue of modal machinery itself (relations of accessibility, satisfaction, transworld correspondence and identity, etc.) and unaffected by what happens in the worlds. But those are not the 'facts' you are thinking of.

@Jo a world where something exisying does not mean that it exists. The law that 'if something is x, then it is x' wouod not apply. There are many weird conc3ptions you can think of. But yet, the fact that if is conceivable in some way is odd

@Conifold the link does not open. And yes i guess a lot of our conception we have reli3s on some things. Modal logic requires,,, well modal logic. Logic requires true and false, etc. But in really wacky worlds do somethings still remain? I imagine identity remains, and even if there is a world where identity does not hold, it still takes identity to state it as i am now. X=x.

It opens for me. The file format is .ps, maybe change your browser settings to ask to save the file rather than to open it directly.  You need a pdf converter like Acrobat Distiller to read it when saved. The link is from his page, there is a direct pdf link but it is behind paywall.

@Conifold by nothing existing outside of possible worlds, does this not itself conceive of itself? It is a statement 'nothing exists outside of possible wo4lds'. 'If something is possible, then it is free from contradiction' etc.

@Conifold what if i posit a world where those dont hold. Or rather, dont even adhere to the hold/no hold schema at all?

Any "necessity", even "absolute", is still relative to the modal system one chooses. But to posit a world you still need a positing machinery. You can exclude any particular "absolutely necessary fact" that it imposes by choosing a different machinery, but not machinery-induced 'facts' as such.

@Annika Could you please elaborate a bit on your comment. I don’t know whether your comment addresses the OP’s question or my foregoing comment. Anyhow, my point was the “existence of impossibilia.”

@JoWehler — it was addressed at OP that “impossible” often is taken to mean logical contradiction which in turn depends on the logic being used

@Conifold what does it mean for a conception to be lroven false? Some people claim truth and existejce are separate. Truth actually adds something to the matter. If this is the case than, what does it add to the round square? What does it mean for a round square to be shown to be false? If exist3nce and truth are separate, than it still exists anyways, but is false?
